# Order French Language in ABC with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column called `Main_Symptom` with multiple rows. When I display the rows, it appears as:

```
Spasms abdominaux
Lié aux piqûres d'insectes
Maux de tête
```

As you can see, it is not ordering alphabetically. Is there something I am doing wrong with the ORDER BY? I am using the utf8_bin collation.
 My current MySQL code in php is:

```
SELECT * FROM `Main DatabaseFrench` where `Main_Symptom`=:mainsymptom ORDER BY Main_Symptom DESC
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-binary-collations.html  `utf8_bin` is binary collation - only the bytes are considered, not the actual characters, so `û` and `u` are two totally different byte/byte-sequences and therefore get sorted differently.

Comment: @MarcB That doesn't address the OP's concern where L is sorted between S and M.

Answer (score 3):

Your logic is wrong:

```
... where `Main_Symptom`=:mainsymptom ORDER BY Main_Symptom DESC
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You are selecting one specific value of `Main_Symptom` so sorting by that value means nothing as there is only one: Ordering by the value you have filtered on does not do anything.

You should order by another column, the one that actually contains the values you have shown in your question.

Comment: Technically I can create a new column with just an english counterpart without accents.. is there another order way I can sort without doing this? I just have the Main_Symptom column.

Comment: @chronotrigga You are missing the point; you should never sort on the column that you have filtered on as that is meaningless.

Comment: @chronotrigga Your query can really only return one record, namely the one where Main_Symptom is the value of :mainsymptom.

Comment: @MrLister Not really, it could be a lot of records but they all have the same `Main_Symptom` value so sorting by it does nothing.

Comment: @jeroen But the OP said "I just have the Main_Symptom column", by which I concluded that that was the only data he was displaying.

Comment: If I only have the Main_Symptom column, what do you recommend is the best course of action? edit: I got it to order by ABC order but the letters with accented words get sent to the bottom

Comment: @chronotrigga You should clarify the question. The data in the question can't possibly be the result of a single column query with one specific value for a filter! Oh, and by now it's clear that it has nothing to do with French.

Comment: @MrLister I'm trying to list my symptoms in ABC order but the accented words (such as Éternuements) get sent to the bottom of the list.

Comment: @MrLister I am starting to dread that the `Main_Symptom` value contains 3 lines separated by new-line characters :-(

Comment: @chronotrigga The word Éternuements appears nowhere in the question.